# RelativeLayout margin problem, text bleeding into other "fields"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

been trying to figure out Android layouts and having a bit of an issue.  i got as far as figuring out how to get the objects in the places i want, using a RelativeLayout (tried LinearLayout and TableLayout combinations, only to find that gravity and attributes weren't doing things i thought they would...) but i've run into an issue with text bleeding behind other text.

[image: Valid XHTML]

the second item demonstrates the problem.  i'd like to have this same layout without the text bleeding.  here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6dip">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text_product"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text_total"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#00aa00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text_count"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_text_total"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text_count"
            android:text="Count: " 
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/item_text_count" 
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/item_text_count" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `maxEms` attribute on the product `TextView` so that it's width can never exceed *n* ems.

That way should be the best solution.

Comment: this was the quickest, simplest solution.  worked like a champ.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put first your `item_text_count` and `text_count` items (I mean, put them above the `text_count` in the XML)... then:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/item_text_total"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_count"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#00aa00"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

As you see, the difference is `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text_count"`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just have to add  `android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item_text_product"` to the second textView, but can't try it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You might try and use a LinearLayout if you don't want overlapping behavior.

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text_product"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text_total"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#00aa00"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_text_count"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_text_total"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/text_count"
            android:text="Count: " 
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/item_text_count" 
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/item_text_count" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_weight="1" causes that view to expand to fill the available space not taken up by the right-hand views.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with wrap_content, with it the view is going to expand to fit its content.

What about shrinking the text and using nested Linear Layouts?